# Celery does not find models when performing the task

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rabbitmq, celery

I'm writing an Api for a telephone newsletter, my code accepts dispatch requests and when it's time to start the newsletter it sends a request to an external Api, which in turn sends the messages themselves.
If you run everything outside of docker, it works fine, but when you run it in docker-compose, the src.newsletter.models.Dispatch.DoesNotExist: Dispatch matching query does not exist.
I'm pretty sure models with this index exist, but celery gives the error

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from src.newsletter.models import Dispatch, Client, Message
from config.settings.development import API_SENDING_URL, API_JWT_TOKEN
import requests


@shared_task
def send_message_to_client(dispatch_id, client_id):
    dispatch = Dispatch.objects.get(id=dispatch_id)
    client = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)

    url = f"{API_SENDING_URL}{client.id}"
    headers = {"Authorization": f"{API_JWT_TOKEN}"}
    data = {
        "id": client.id,
        "phone": client.phone_number,
        "text": dispatch.text_message,
    }

    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        print(response.status_code)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            message = Message.objects.create(
                status='S',
                dispatch=dispatch,
                client=client
            )
        elif response.status_code == 401:
            message = Message.objects.create(
                status='F',
                dispatch=dispatch,
                client=client
            )
        elif response.status_code == 400 or response.elapsed.total_seconds() > 10:
            # Повторная попытка отправки
            try:
                response_retry = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
                if response_retry.status_code == 200:
                    message = Message.objects.create(
                        status='S',
                        dispatch=dispatch,
                        client=client
                    )
                else:
                    message = Message.objects.create(
                        status='F',
                        dispatch=dispatch,
                        client=client
                    )
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
                message = Message.objects.create(
                    status='F',
                    dispatch=dispatch,
                    client=client
                )
        else:
            message = Message.objects.create(
                status='F',
                dispatch=dispatch,
                client=client
            )
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        message = Message.objects.create(
            status='F',
            dispatch=dispatch,
            client=client
        )
    except Exception as e:
        message = Message.objects.create(
            status='F',
            dispatch=dispatch,
            client=client
        )
        # Обработка ошибки при выполнении запроса
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator, RegexValidator
from django.utils import timezone


class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex=r'^7[0-9]{10}$',
                message='Phone number must be in the format 7XXXXXXXXXX'
            )
        ]
    )
    # Все российские операторы имеют код от 900 до 997, в тз не указано нужны именно российские операторы или нет
    # поэтому я ограничился этими кодами
    mobile_operator_code = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(900), MaxValueValidator(997)])
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Dispatch(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    text_message = models.TextField()
    client_filter = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def send(self):
        from .tasks import send_message_to_client
        clients = []
        try:
            if 900 <= int(self.client_filter) <= 997:
                clients = Client.objects.filter(mobile_operator_code=int(self.client_filter))
        except ValueError:
            clients = Client.objects.filter(tag__contains=self.client_filter)
        for client in clients:
            send_message_to_client.delay(self.id, client.id)


class Message(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('S', 'Sent'),
        ('F', 'Failed'),
        ('P', 'Pending'),
    ]
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    dispatch = models.ForeignKey(Dispatch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=solutionfactory
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=solutionfactory
      - POSTGRES_DB=solutionfactory
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data


  rabbitmq:
    restart: always
    hostname: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_NODENAME: "rabbit@localhost"
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "rabbitmq"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "rabbitmq"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672


  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    hostname: web
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    links:
      - "rabbitmq:test"
      - db
      - rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - db
#    networks:
#      - my-network
#    network_mode: "host"


  celery-worker:
    restart: always
    build: .
    working_dir: /code
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    command: bash -c "
      rm -rf /tmp/celery*.pid &
      python -m celery -A config worker --beat --loglevel=info"

    links:
      - "rabbitmq:test"
      - db
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq


  flower:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "sleep 30 && celery -A config.celery flower --address=0.0.0.0 --port=5555 --loglevel=info"
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    links:
      - "rabbitmq:test"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.10

WORKDIR /solutionfactory-test-task

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION=ignore

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /solutionfactory-test-task/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

COPY . /solutionfactory-test-task/


RUN python manage.py migrate
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
# copy project
COPY . .
# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

error message

```
task-celery-worker-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
task-celery-worker-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 477, in trace_task
task-celery-worker-1  |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
task-celery-worker-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 760, in __protected_call__
task-celery-worker-1  |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
task-celery-worker-1  |   File "/code/src/newsletter/tasks.py", line 9, in send_message_to_client
task-celery-worker-1  |     dispatch = Dispatch.objects.get(id=dispatch_id)
task-celery-worker-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
task-celery-worker-1  |     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
solutionfactory-test-task-celery-worker-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
task-celery-worker-1  |     raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
task-celery-worker-1  | src.newsletter.models.Dispatch.DoesNotExist: Dispatch matching query does not exist.
```

I tried to find something like this on the forum, but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issue when using Celery + DRF with atomic transactions.

often times what happens is that you call the celery task before the current transaction gets committed to the database, so the task might run before your `Dispatch` object has actually been created. if that turns out to be your issue, a good way to ensure that the transaction has been committed before you send the task to celery is to [leverage Django's `transaction.on_commit()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit):

```py
from django.db import transaction


transaction.on_commit(lambda: send_message_to_client.delay(self.id, client.id))
```